# How can I identify certain days of the week from a range of date cells using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have several columns of data, each under a particular date. I want to identify particular days of the week so I can separate this data into two tables, each for particular days of the week. I will need to do this as part of a macro.

Thanks for your help & advice.

Comment: You have to share example

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `getDay()` method of the Data object. MDN helps [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay):

> The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.

For an example the custom formula

```
/**
 *
 * @customformula
 */
function CUSTOMFORMULA(data) {
  if (Array.isArray(data))
    return data.map(function(row) {
      return row.map(function(cell) {
        return getDayOrNot_(cell);
      });
    });
  return getDayOrNot_(data);
}
/**
 *
 * @param {Date} date
 */
function getDayOrNot_(date) {
  return date && date.getTime ? date.getDay() : date;
}
```

In any ways with scripts you can use the next code `var weekday = date && date.getTime ? date.getDay() : date;` as basic.

[image]

Also `WEEKNUM` of Google Sheet formula works fine

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKDAY(A2:A20))
```

[image]